# $F(X_{1}\cap X_{2}) = F (X_{1})\cap F(X_{2})$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let f be a function from $A$ to $B$ . Show that $f$ is $1-1$ if and only if for

$X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ all subsets of $A$ and have $$F(X_{1}\cap X_{2}) = F (X_{1})\cap F(X_{2}) $$
I'm a little confused about how to solve this problem, I'd appreciate any indication to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is injective, all you have to do is prove that given any two subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$ of $A$ the following two inclusions hold:

1. $F(X_1\cap X_2)\subset F(X_1)\cap F(X_2)$
2. $F(X_1)\cap F(X_2)\subset F(X_1\cap X_2)$

(For the second point: let $y\in F(X_1)\cap F(X_2)$, then $y\in F(X_1)$ and $y\in F(X_2)$, so that there exist $x_1\in X_1$ and $x_2\in X_2$ such that $y=F(x_1)$ and $y=F(x_2)$. Since $F$ is injective, $x_1=x_2=x$, i.e., $y=F(x)$ where $x\in X_1\cap X_2$.)

For the other implication... Let $x_1,\,x_2\in A$ be such that $F(x_1)=F(x_2)$ and let $X_1=\{ x_1\}$ and $X_2=\{ x_2\}$. Then it follows that $F(X_1)\cap F(X_2)=F(X_1\cap X_2)$. Note that $X_1\cap X_2$ cannot be empty, otherwise we would have $F(X_1\cap X_2)=F(\emptyset )=\emptyset$ which is absurd. Then $x_1=x_2$ and $F$ is injective.